# problem in website viewing

Tags: theming

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function omega_theme() in /home/itcom/public_html/sites/all/themes/libra/template.php on line 27

Whenever I browse my site, I get this message, and I am not able to login to the site. Clean URLs are not enabled in this site.

I would like to know how I can change the default current theme from code, and any other solution to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Libra](http://drupal.org/project/libra) theme is a sub-theme of the [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) theme, but seemingly the Omega theme is not present (otherwise, omega_theme() would be defined). Make sure that you have placed the Omega theme in /home/itcom/public_html/sites/all/themes/omega and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess somewhere in your template.php file in your enabled theme you're making a call to omega_theme() function. If your theme is a subtheme of omega, you should let drupal know about that by putting this **base theme = omega** in your **.info** file in your theme folder. Also, **omega theme** should be present in your drupal themes folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you uploaded the Omega theme properly. The first time I used Omega, I took the "Omega" directory only from the parent "Omega" folder and had similar issues but you need the entire folder that has "starterkits", "alpha" etc... See my screen capture to confirm your directory structure is correct.

[image: Omega Directory Structure]